# if ((bytes[FLAGS_OFFSET] & 0x0F) != 0) throw new

Tags: java

What exactly is this code testing for? It's for an ID3 tagging library. I've just starting learning about "anding" recently. As far as I can gather, the "&0x0F" moves the bits over to the right.

Any elucidation you can provide on this if statement would be greatly appreciated.

```
protected static final int FLAGS_OFFSET = 5;
if ((bytes[FLAGS_OFFSET] & 0x0F) != 0) throw new UnsupportedTagException("Unrecognised bits in  header");
```

The 5th byte contains a flag:

```
ID3v2 flags             %abc00000
```

["%x is used to indicate a bit with unknown content."](http://id3.org/id3v2.3.0)

[a - Unsynchronisation
Bit 7 in the 'ID3v2 flags' indicates whether or not unsynchronisation is used (see section 5 for details); a set bit indicates usage.](http://id3.org/id3v2.3.0#ID3v2_header)

[b - Extended header
The second bit (bit 6) indicates whether or not the header is followed by an extended header. The extended header is described in section 3.2.](http://id3.org/id3v2.3.0#ID3v2_header)

[c - Experimental indicator
The third bit (bit 5) should be used as an 'experimental indicator'. This flag should always be set when the tag is in an experimental stage.](http://id3.org/id3v2.3.0#ID3v2_header)

Comment: it doesn't shift bits, it masks.... in your case 0x0F masks the top 4 bits, zeroing them out

Comment: Can you tell me more Mitch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit in the result of `&` is a 1 if both operands had a 1 set in that bit, so for example:

```
  01010101
& 00001111
==========
  00000101
```

`0x0F` is `1111` in binary. (This is called a "mask".) So the expression says "if any of the lowest 4 bits are set in the byte at index 5, throw an exception".

Comment: Okay. So the top three bits in this byte that I would be concerned with are: "A,B,and C", correct? Why was 0x0F chosen by the coder in this example?

Comment: 0x0F was chosen because it isolates the 4 bits they are checking. From looking at the documentation, it seems that the a, b and c bits are not the bits this expression is checking. Though I don't really understand the importance of the four they *are* checking. The doc says there are actually 5 unused bits so it seems to me the mask should be 0x1F. (Unless the tagging library has decided to use the extra bit for something of its own.)

Comment: I could be relating the wrong piece of code to the wrong problem. The method is [unpackHeader](https://github.com/mpatric/mp3agic/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mpatric/mp3agic/AbstractID3v2Tag.java). Your explanation was very helpful - it will help me understand the code better. Thanks, Radioef.

Comment: I think you've got the right relation here, and after doing a little inspection I think I'm right they are using an extra bit. It's called `FOOTER_BIT` and it's used by `ID3v24Tag`. And no problem. : )

Comment: I see it now. Thanks again, Radiodef.